# Syntax behind min(must_visit, key=lambda x:...)

Tags: python, function, lambda, anonymous-function

I'm looking at the Greedy implementation of TSP problem here https://pastebin.com/NeMbdzdr

The following line is finding the nearest point with the latest point in path,

```
nearest = min(must_visit, key=lambda x: distance(path[-1], x))
```

What is the meaning of `lambda x: distance(path[-1], x)` and how would it be written as a separate function?

Comment: `def key(x): return distance(path[-1], x)`

Comment: Why you delete the question about recipes?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I think I got my own answer (it's correct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your lambda function will return what `distance(path[-1], x)` returns, so the `nerest` will be the minimum element from `must_visit` where `distance(path[-1], x)`  is at minimum

equivalent function:

```
def my_func(x):
    return distance(path[-1], x)
```

and you can use it like :

```
nerest = min(must_visit, key=my_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

path[-1] returns the last point

distance(path[-1], x) returns distance between last point and point x.

min function iterate over must_visit and calculate distance between last point and points in must_visit, and returns minimum of them.